pgAdmin 4 for Windows, query error, <column> does not exist, hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column <column>
I can run this query:
select * from picker_data_entity

I can run this query:
select * from bip

but, when I am trying to run this query:
select * from picker_data_entity join bip on bip.id = picker_data_entity.bipId 

or this query:
select "*" from picker_data_entity join bip on "bip.id" = "picker_data_entity.bipId"

I get this error:
ERROR:  column picker_data_entity.bipid does not exist
LINE 1: ...ct * from picker_data_entity join bip on bip.id = picker_dat...
                                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you meant to reference the column "picker_data_entity.bipId". 

SQL state: 42703
Character: 55

Please help me run this simple join query. Thank you!

well, these two queries worked:
SELECT * FROM picker_data_entity JOIN bip on bip.id = "bipId"
SELECT * FROM picker_data_entity, bip

You are attempting to reference columns via table_name.column_name format. However you have enclosed the entire string in double quotes ("). this makes it a single identofier that just happens to have a dot (.) in that name. Since the table_name and column_name are each identifiers each has to be enclosed seperatly within double quotes. Since the table names do not contain capitals they do not need double quoting and neither does id. Also "*" would be interpreted as an identifier. So try:
select "*" 
  from picker_data_entity 
   join bip on bip."id" = picker_data_entity."bipId"

